# Managing project dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, build, dependency-management, robotium

I see a number of posts on this, but I'm still struggling.

I've got a workspace with two projects, one with the robotium library and one using it(we'll call this one foo). I would like to click run on foo, and have it re-compile robotium into a jar, add it to foo's build path, and then run foo. How can I do this?

Also, I'm starting to learn maven so I'm not opposed to doing this that way, I just don't know how -- I've been assuming this is something Eclipse can do standalone.

Comment: Distribute Android library project as a self-contained jar file is not yet officially supported by android SDK, neither does android-maven-plugin. The thing used in android-maven-plugin is called **apklib**, I have written an answer briefly explained how it work before [at here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823392/android-maven-plugin-apklib-mojo-doesnt-include-compiled-r-in-resulting-apklib/8826739#8826739), worth to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set an android project as a library, and in the foo project reference to that library.

```
project properties -> android -> libraries -> add project in workspace
```

In that way you can have your robotium project with your changes and when you run the foo project it will compile and link the library project, this is also used to separate your project in common libraries, etc.

You will need the Robotium project in your workspace :)

Answer (score 0):

Using maven, you should define the robotium projects as a dependency of your main project. It is also advisable to have a parent pom, where all the projects are defined as modules, including the main project. If you then start a maven build on the parent project, all the modules will be built first.

In [this book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring.html) you can find a well explained step-by-step setup of a maven multimodule project (with downloadable code).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in eclipse.
Myproject(Foo) > Rightclick > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Class Folder (robotium)