# R.java will not be generated (android-maven-plugin)

Tags: android, maven

I tried different goals. `mvn package` results in `package R does not exist`, `mvn android:generate-sources` results in `BUILD SUCCESS` but no `R.java` will be created.

I would like to pack my classes into a jar container (not apk) because I would like to use it as a library in other projects.

AndroidManifest.xml: (minimal setup, because there are no Activities)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

default.properties:

```
android.library=true
target=android-8
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

The only resource is `./res/layout/example.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android-maven-plugin has no capability to generate a fully functional jar (contains all compiled class file, resources, manifest and etc) from Android library project.

The solution given by android-maven-plugin is [apklib](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib), which is simply a zip of the library project (has same directory structure contains raw java file, resource, manifest and etc). I have explained a bit more about how apklib works [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823392/android-maven-plugin-apklib-mojo-doesnt-include-compiled-r-in-resulting-apklib/8826739#8826739), for some sample projects, check out [maven-android-plugin-samples/libraryprojects](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/libraryprojects).

The furthest android-maven-plugin can go is a jar that contains only compiled class file, no resource, this is covered by the default <packaging>apklib<packaging> build life cycle and generated along with the .apklib file.