# How do I create an apklib for a non maven project

Tags: android, maven, android-library, android-maven-plugin

My android application depends on an android library project which comes from a 3rd party. I am switching my build environment over to maven and following the samples has gone fairly smooth but the last step is this. I don't understand what I actually need to ***do***. I've read the apklib page [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib). I've never seen a document dance around what you actually do better than this document. It contains 1 snippet of how you reference an apklib but no information at all about how you actually generate it?

Also, my project structure looks like this

```
/projectroot/app   (main application android project source code)
/projectroot/shared/lib1  
/projectroot/shared/lib2 (3rd party lib i don't want to create pom.xml for)
```

I have projectroot/pom.xml with a modules section like so:

```
<modules>
    <module>shared/lib1</module>
    <module>shared/lib2</module>
    <module>app</module>
</modules>
```

Is this the correct? In all the module examples I see they refer to folders direct children whereas mine are nested further.

Main thing I'm looking for is how to make lib2 an apklib to reference from app/pom.xml.

Comment: Couldn't agree more about that document. The section called "Creating an apklib to use in your project" doesn't actually tell you how to create it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned [in the link you referenced](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib):

> ### Compatible with non-Maven Android Library Projects!
>
> The generated .apklib file will have the layout of a standard Android/Eclipse library project. This means that regardless of your Maven layout, the layout inside the .apklib file will be that source code is in "src/" instead of "src/main/java/", but still interpreted correctly when used in an Android/Maven application project. This is to be compatible with non-Maven developers' library projects, which is important to grow the Android developer community.
>
> ### Use other non-Maven developers' libraries
>
> It also means we can take any external Android library project zip file (from non-Maven developers) and do mvn install:install-file ... on it and simply start using it as a dependency.
>
> ### Share your .apklib with non-Maven developers
>
> To share your .apklib file with a non-Maven developer, they will probably feel more comfortable if you rename it to .zip. They can then simply unpack it in a directory and use it from there.

If it is a mavenized  Android library project, simply run `mvn clean install` to create the apklib and get it installed in your local Maven repository.

If it is a regular Android library project, simply zip the project folder (better to strip all unnecessary  IDE generated files), rename my-lib.zip to my-lib.apklib, then run [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) to install my-lib.apklib into your local Maven repository.

Note that in your multi-module maven project, if the child module lib2 is not mavenized, you may get some configuration error when running maven build, it is called multi-module Maven project after all so does not make much sense to include a non-mavenized child project. If the lib2 is not mavenized yet, either mavenize it as part of the mutli-module maven project or remove it from  mutli-module maven project and maintain it separately (from both command-line build via apklib and IDE development via the source).

Also note that project building in Maven and Eclipse are totally different story, if you are creating/importing the project into IDE, you need the library project source anyway. If lib2 is mavenized as part of the multi-module project, it will be imported and setup automatically when import the parent project, otherwise, you may need import and setup the standalone project manually. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831481/apklib-does-not-get-installed-in-maven-repo/8831891#8831891) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823392/android-maven-plugin-apklib-mojo-doesnt-include-compiled-r-in-resulting-apklib/8826739#8826739) for more details.

Comment: I created an apklib using this in my pom.xml   <packaging>apklib</packaging> but it has created it without /src, only  /res and /libs when exploded.