# What is an apkLIB and how do I use one?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to put a SwipeListView onto an Activity, however I can't seem to figure out how to import it.  I got the library from here: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Then I followed the directions in the Issues section found here: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/17

Unfortunately, There were still errors after I had followed the directions.

Instead, I'd like to try and import the library with the apkLIB approach.  I don't know if that is independent of Maven, but I also attempted it that way, but to no success.

When I tried installing it as a Maven Dependency, I followed the directions here: http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/

However, after doing so, I did not see as the screenshot suggested a 'MAVEN DEPENDENCIES' folder in my project hierarchy. I am even more confused with Maven than I was trying to install the library on my own.

I really don't know what else to do at this point.  Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: "There were still errors" is a useless description of your problem.

Comment: "R cannot be resolved to a variable" was in my SwipeListView.java file, as well as my PackageAdapter.java file.  I don't know how to clear those up. These errors are associated with layout/ files, however after putting the layout files in both the SwipeListView project and my project, neither seemed to resolve the error.

Comment: There will be details in the Eclipse Console and/or Problems view about specifically what errors are preventing Android from regenerating your `R` class.

Comment: what s d problem..be specific ..

Comment: [What is an apkLIB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823392/android-maven-plugin-apklib-mojo-doesnt-include-compiled-r-in-resulting-apklib/8826739#8826739) and [how do I use one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831481/apklib-does-not-get-installed-in-maven-repo/8831891#8831891).